# Need to avoid redirection for GitHub access and generate the access token

Tags: github-api

Is it possible to avoid the redirection for Github access. Ie can i pass the username and password internally and generate the token without showing the user github page for login. Please help

Answer (score 0):

When you use Basic Auth you can just send the username and password in plaintext but when you use OAuth you have to show the page.

Comment: Thank you Eragonio. I'm trying to generate the access token through PHP Curl. But the requirement to get the token without showing the login page. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You can't generate the token with Basic Auth. You can send your credentials plaintext OR you can show the login page and use OAuth with the token.

Comment: Sorry but i'm wrong. Looks like it works this way: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization

Comment: i tried the /authorizations url as mentioned in: developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization . Even this was redirecting to login page.

Comment: i just need to avoid this page and handle the process in backend.

Comment: I tried like this:  

  $url = "https://github.com/authorizations";

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
  $content = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

Comment: You may try to first authenticate with Basic Auth and then make the new token.

Comment: If this worked you may consider to mark my answer as correct.